# xCode and Swift tutorial confusion

Tags: xcode, swift

I'm following Apple's tutorial for Ios app development and it says to look for the viewcontroller.swift file, but the only files that are showing up in xcode are viewcontroller.h and viewcontroller.m. What's the difference between these files and where is the .swift file?

Comment: The project you created is in Objective-C. Your tutorial is for Swift. You should start over and create a new project and make sure Swift is selected from the programming language drop down menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It Depends on the Language You select if You Choose Objective-C You'll have ViewController.h and ViewController.m as well as you choose Swift You'll have ViewController.swift file Simple as that.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That is because You have selected Objective-c as language while creating new project. So create a new project and select Swift as language and you will see ViewController.swift file in the project navigator.[image]

[image]